# How to load an image from drawable and convert to a bitmap

Tags: java, android, image, bitmap, drawable

I have an image in the drawable folder and I want to convert into a bitmap and then convert to byte[] to store into a database, I can convert the bitmap to a byte array but I'm not able to get the image from drawable since `Bitmap photo = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image);` returns null. How to do it?

what i have for the moment

```
Bitmap photo = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image); //this returns null
if(photo != null)
byte[] bytes = getBitmapAsByteArray(photo);

//this works
DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
databaseHelper.add("DEFAULT",bytes);
```

UPDATE:
when I set the bitmap to image with `photo.setImageBitmap(bitmap);` after it retrieves information from database it does not appear, seems that the store does not work

I'm storing info into database like this

```
private static byte[] getBitmapAsByteArray(Bitmap bitmap) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0, outputStream);
        return outputStream.toByteArray();
    }

public boolean addUserInformation(String username, byte[] picture){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("USERNAME", username);
        if(picture!=null) {
            values.put("PICTURE", picture);
        }
        id = db.insert(TABLE_NAME1, null, values);
        }
        db.close();
        if(id == -1)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
```

and retrieve information like this

```
Cursor data = databaseHelper.getUserInformation();
        if(data.moveToFirst()) {
            mUsername = data.getString(1);
            bytes = data.getBlob(2);
            if(bytes!=null)
                profilePhoto = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, data.getBlob(2).length);
        }
```

with getUserInformation() inside database class

```
public Cursor getUserInformation(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME1;
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query,null);
        return c;
    }
```

Comment: why would you want to "convert" `VectorDrawable` to raw pixels? the main purpose of `VectorDrawable` is to avoid rasterized graphics and use vector graphics instead

Comment: I need to store the image into a SQLite database as byte array

Comment: so why do you use `VectorDrawable` at all?

Comment: what should I use to take an .xml image from the drawable folder and convert it to a byte array? @pskink

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following method should work fine:

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromVectorDrawable(Context context, int drawableId) {
    Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, drawableId);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        drawable = (DrawableCompat.wrap(drawable)).mutate();
    }
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(),
            drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    drawable.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;
}
```

`build.gradle (project-level)`

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-alpha5'
    }
```

`build.gradle (app-level)`

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    ...
}
...
```

Or, you can use `android-ktx` in Kotlin too like this which works for any subclass of `Drawable`:

`build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.0-alpha1'
}
```

Then use `Drawable#toBitmap()` like this:

```
val bitmap = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(requireContext(), drawableId).toBitmap()
```

Comment: does not recognize BitmapDescriptor class it gives me cannot resolve symbol, what library shall I import?

Comment: @james, then use `AppCompatResources` instead of `ContextCompat` here in this line: `Drawable drawable = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context, drawableId);`

Answer (score 1):

Use This

`Bitmap photo = ((BitmapDrawable) getDrawable(R.drawable.R.drawable.image)).getBitmap();`

hopefully, work fine ;)

Comment: crash with android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable. Also it requires api level 21, is there a way to include older api too?

Comment: It should only work if the drawable is already a `BitmapDrawable`. Should crash with `ClassCastException` in all other cases, when the drawable is anything but `BitmapDrawable`, like `VectorDrawable` or `LayerDrawable` or `ScaleDrawable` etc

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a very simple way. Add Glide to your project like this -

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
```

Then take a global Bitmap variable and call like this-

private Bitmap imageBitmap;

```
Glide.with(this)
        .asBitmap()
        .load(R.drawable.image)
        .into(new CustomTarget<Bitmap>() {
            @Override
            public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
                imageView.setImageBitmap(resource);
                //Save the bitmap to your global bitmap
                imageBitmap = resource;
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadCleared(@Nullable Drawable placeholder) {
            }
        });
```

Now pass the imageBitmap to your getBitmapAsByteArray() to convert to byteArray, so that you can save this in your SQLite Database.

Hope it helps!